# Diffraction problem - How do I interpret

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, diffraction

Here is a problem on diffraction -
Diffraction pattern of single slit of width 0.5 cm is formed by a lens of focal length of 40 cm. calculate the distance between first dark and next bright fringe from the axis. Wavelength of the light used is 4890 Angstrom.

I am confused by following statement of the problem:
"distance between first dark and next bright fringe from the axis"

it is like saying calculate distance between x and y from m. Here x and y are bands and y is a line.

My first hunch was - do not first dark and next bright lie next to each other? what is the point in asking distance between them? Looks like the problem is asking us to calculate width of first bright fringe (what is pretty straight forward).

Referring to one of earlier post - what is the point in asking distance between fringes?

Answer (score 2):

The diffraction at the single slit will form an sinc pattern. The image below (taken from [this hyperphysics article on single slit diffraction](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/sinslit.html)) shows what this will look like.  The first dark fringe is just outside the large central lobe and the next bright fringe is the second largest lobe just above the dark fringe. Good luck!

[image: Airy pattern from hyperphysics]
<sub>(source: [gsu.edu](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/imgpho/sinslit.gif))</sub>

Comment: My problem and confusion remains. how do i interpret "distance between fringes"? fringes are not points or lines - they are regions.

Comment: Use the minimum for the dark part and the maximum for the bright part...